# Is android:allowBackup a security risk for android applications

Tags: android, security

is setting

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="true"
```

considered a security risk for android applications?
doesnt it expose both user data and the application source code to hackers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be opinion based.

The [Data Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup) feature does only upload additional application data. It does not upload your APK or source code.

From a security standpoint, uploading user data to an external services is always worse than just leaving it local. If you deal with very sensitive data, you shouldn't upload it.

Comment: i thought by enabling back up it allows the user to use a file manager application to take a backup of your application apk, then using android studio you can copy the backed up apk and decompile it

Comment: @Hector Users always have access to the APK. You can just copy the compiled APK with ADB and use tools like `apktool` to decompile it into a somewhat better readbale form.

Answer (score 2):

It is not opinion based.

If you have accountability over your customer's data, then you should follow some hardening guidelines. A serious customer will ask what your security standards are and will most definitely pentest the app for weaknesses.

A backup can allow an unauthorized user to extract sensitive data, should they have physical access to the device, even without rooting it first.

Answer (score 1):

There is another piece, if you allow backup then someone can extract your application data(even the application private one as e.g SharedPreferences) using simple `adb backup` [command](https://medium.com/@rickbuiten/how-to-hack-the-android-auto-backup-for-apps-functionality-8eb0ce3290a8).

So to answer your question it could pose a serious risk to user data. Regarding the app source, on the other hand, source code is available to everyone who installed your app and enabled developer options on his device. Thus being able to get your APK by using `adb pull` command and examine it. But this is a whole different story not connected to android backup.